Breaking content tree to separate modules with SCS
I am using Sitecore CLI for item serialization. I have the next content structure which I want to serialize to different modules:
sitecore/
├─ Content/
│  ├─ MyProject/
│  │  ├─ Home/
│  │  │  ├─ Events/
│  │  │  ├─ Settings/
│  │  │  │  ├─ Events/

The events related items should go to a separate module. So the first module has the following structure in the Includes:
{
  "name": "content",
  "path": "/sitecore/content/MyProject",
  "rules": [
    {
      "path": "/Home/Settings",
      "scope": "SingleItem"
    },
    {
      "path": "/Home",
      "scope": "SingleItem"
    },
    {
      "path": "*",
      "scope": "Ignored"
    }
  ]
}

The second one for Events (it shows the desired behavior but my tested variations aren't working):
{
  "name": "content/MyProject",
  "path": "/sitecore/content/MyProject/Home",
  "scope": "DescendantsOnly",
  "rules": [
    {
      "path": "/Events",
      "scope": "ItemAndDescendants"
    },
    {
      "path": "/Settings",
      "scope": "DescendantsOnly", // Scope DescendantsOnly isn't available in rules
      "rules": [                  // Nested rules not supported (I believe)
        {
          "path": "/Events",
          "scope": "ItemAndDescendants"
        },
        {
          "path": "*",
          "scope": "Ignored"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "path": "*",
      "scope": "Ignored"
    }
  ]
}

But the second module include isn't valid. At the same time need to set scope for items under /Settings because without it they basically ignored and I get another error about that.
Am I missing something or this is not a way how SCS works and I need to have separate branch for Events to serialize, e.g. moving Events settings under the main Events node?
I also tried to add a reference inside Events module to the first module, but the issues are the same.
Adding two separate includes doesn't work because it cause some conflicts where item with same id included in same path (I believe it's due to /Events and /Settings/Events share same parent).

Did you tryed to specify only the rule for Settings with DescendantsOnly scope and removing the /Settings/Events in the second rule.

@ckhanna There might be items from other modules like Navigation, so I had to include separate items and ignore others.

Ya but the rule you specified for Settings/Events will be already covered because in your Settings path you are specifying with Descedants as scope.

Okay, you've pointed out the problem that by adding /Settings DescendantsOnly I'm also including other children of it that I don't need.
I updated the question but I am not sure If nested rules are allowed because there is no property for them in documentation https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/latest/developer-tools/sitecore-content-serialization-configuration-reference.html#rules
Still I get the same error with this setup.

The reason you are facing this issue is because DescendantsOnly property is not supported inside the rules section, as TreeRuleScope enum supports only these types.

In order to resolve the issue you are getting above, add below configuration for rules.
{
  "name": "content/MyProject",
  "path": "/sitecore/content/MyProject/Home",
  "scope": "DescendantsOnly",
  "rules": [
   {
    "path": "/Events",
    "scope": "ItemAndDescendants"
   },
   {
    "path": "/Settings/Events",
    "scope": "ItemAndDescendants"
   },
   {
    "path": "/Settings",
    "scope": "SingleItem"
   },
   {
    "path": "*",
    "scope": "ignored"
   }
 ]
}

Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issue.

If I also include the /Settings item in the Events module, I get an error about duplicate since SCS doesn't support serialization of the same item in multiple places which is reasonable. And I cant just remove the include from first module and leave only in the seconds one because If I create a third module with its own item under /Settings the same problem will rise.
Regarding the error, now it makes sense, thanks.

It would make sense just to add a reference to the first module where the /Settings item is serialized but due to Ignore in the Events module (I believe) it complains about missing /Settings item even with reference.
